# How to copy files to the timestamp generated directory?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Hello I am trying to copy all files from Documents directory to the backup directory that has a timestamp. So I have created a directory called `bk$( the time stamp of the directory)` and I am trying to copy files from the Documents directory to the new created directory that is unique. This will be in a `crontab` backing up files from documents and when the backup will kick in, it will create new directory for each backup that is uniquely identified by the directory timestamp. For some reason I cannot get the `cp` or `cpio -mdp`.

```
bkdate="date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S"
PATH=/home/user/backup/
bksource="/home/user/Documents/"

mkdir /home/user/backup/"bk$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S)"
cp $bksource * ls | tail -l | $PATH
```

I could of went with the `ctime` but unfortunately it does not work with the directory creation date.

This was my approach but with the latest created directory and not file

```
find $HOME -type d -daystart ctime 0
```

If someone could please help me out to copy to that new directory, I would really appreciate it.

Solution:
This is one solution using target. I am open to other ways that could be used for this purpose.

```
bkdest=/home/user/backup
bksource=/home/user/Documents
target=${bkdest}/bk.$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S)
mkdir -p $target
cp ${bksource}/* ${target}/
```

Comment: `ctime` is metadata change time, NOT creation time

Answer (score 2):

You set the location in a variable named $PATH. This variable has a special meaning as the search path where the shell will look for commands to execute. By setting it to a directory which you created (and which therefore is empty), you just made sure that the shell can't find any command anymore.

Rename that variable to something else. All will be fine then.

Comment: So do you mean to leave $PATH variable as is and then just copy files "cp $bksource * $PATH" and that will work and copy to that particular created folder that has been created previously?
Thanks!

Comment: Nonono. *rename* the PATH variable to something else. You will still need a variable where you store that. Just don't call it PATH,

Comment: Thanks, I'm still a bit confused, then how is $PATH variable being used? it doesn't know the location to which it is assigned. Where am I calling the path, to the "cp" destination?

Comment: If you could please provide an example of how this should work, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!